# Python-pyqt4 QCalendarWidget visibility

Tags: python, plugins, pyqt, pyqt4

I am working with python plugins.I designed my form using **PYQT4** designer.I used two **QCalendarWidget** on my form.

I retrieved selected values of calendar using

```
date1 = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
```

But i wanted to make calendar invisible on load of the form.Once you click specific radio button,calendar should be visible.I tried googling but did not get **visibility** property of  **QCalendarWidget** .
How do i make that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `show()`, `hide()`, `setVisible(is_visible)`, etc... functions of base `QWidget`.

[List of All Members for QCalendarWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget-members.html)

So, when you are initializing widgets, call `self.calendarWidget.hide()`. Then in radio button toggled handler, call `self.calendarWidget.show()` or `self.calendarWidget.setVisible(True)`

Also, you can connect radio button `toggled(bool)` signal, to `QWidget.setVisible(bool)` slot in QtDesigner:

[image: signal connecting]